# Can not log in to Drupal 7 admin after changing to HTTPS. Access Denied and cookie not set

Tags: drupal

I can no longer log into Drupal 7's admin area after adding SSL certificate and forcing HTTPS in url.

The website was previously served via HTTP protocol and worked perfectly fine. I would also like to mention that if I revert back to HTTP mode, the site will work as expected. However, I am trying to implement HTTPS.

Additionally, while logging in, I have noticed that the cookie response would be sent by the server but it would get deleted immediately leading to access denied message.

So far, after going through mixed response in the internet, I have played around with session.cookie, $base_url and $cookie_domain variables within settings.php file. I haven't found a solution yet.

Has anyone bumped into this problem? Your response will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Tried different browser?

Comment: Have you read this instruction: [Enabling HTTP Secure (HTTPS)](https://www.drupal.org/https-information)?

Comment: I went over the document and compared apache server's vitrual host configuration file for both HTTP and HTTPS. HTTPS seems to be missing allowoveride all bit. However, the site is working fine. The problem is only when I try to logging in - it would throw access denied error.

Can this error, by any chance, linked to how the virtual host is configured?

Answer (score 0):

In apache server
Go to .httaccess
Add # in front of `RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]` to disable http
It looks like this `# RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]`
This solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is a fairly old post but here is what happened with my site.

We installed a new SSL certificate and somehow the .htaccess file ended up empty, and I do mean 100% blank.

This means easy fix, download latest drupal core and just replace the **.htaccess** file along with the core files, usually you want skip this to preserve all additional code added for html compression and such, but in this case that is redundant.

After the **.htaccess** was replaced I then added the compression and rerouting code like before and problem solved.

Hope this helps someone else out, I know I will always be checking the .htaccess files first if it happens again.

Answer (score -1):

```
Disable in .httaccess
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Could you try to explain a bit more how you answer will solve the asker's problem?