# Unable to log in to admin area after installing SSL certificate on Drupal

Tags: ssl, drupal, authentication, admin, redirect-loop

We have recently installed an SSL certificate to our fairly old version of Drupal. The front end of it works well, however, we are now unable to log in to the admin area. We put this problem on our servers who claims the website now goes into a continuous redirect look, causing the site to crash. here is what they said.

*"I have taken a further look at this and we can see some pages have specific rules in place that are forcing them to use HTTP this is then causing an issue with the redirect to HTTPS, this is essentially creating a loop as the Site goes to the HTTP which gets redirected to HTTPS, which the page then redirects back to HTTP and so on. You will need to review the content of the site and to remove the redirect(s) to HTTP for any pages that have this, alternatively, we can remove the redirect to HTTPS (However this defeats the purpose of having the SSL Certificate then). Please let me know if you would like me to remove the HTTPS redirect."*

The same problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37110061/can-not-log-in-to-drupal-7-admin-after-changing-to-https-access-denied-and-cook?answertab=votes#tab-top) at stack overflow. However, the answer is very vague considering it's a change to the .htaccess file.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

put this line at the en of settings.php
$conf['https'] = TRUE;